# What is wrong with the val notNull[T]: T => Boolean = _ != null from Scala in Depth

Tags: function, scala

I tried running the following snippet from [Scala in Depth](http://www.manning.com/suereth/) in the REPL:

```
val notNull[T]: T => Boolean = _ != null
```

The interpreter threw me the following errors:

```
<console>:7: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$bang$eq(null))
       val notNull[T]: T => Boolean = _ != null
                                      ^
<console>:7: error: not found: type T
       val notNull[T]: T => Boolean = _ != null
                       ^
<console>:7: error: not found: type notNull
       val notNull[T]: T => Boolean = _ != null
           ^
<console>:7: error: not found: type T
       val notNull[T]: T => Boolean = _ != null
                   ^

scala> val notNull[T](f1: T => Boolean) = _ != null
<console>:1: error: ')' expected but '=>' found.
       val notNull[T](f1: T => Boolean) = _ != null
```

Maybe I am not understanding the statement here but isn't the statement from the book basically saying, declare a val notNull of type T which returns a function that takes T as an argument and returns a Boolean. The `_ ! = null executes the function by taking the argument and comparing it with null, essentially returning a Boolean?

Why is the compiler throwing all these errors here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It needs to be a `def` to work. Val's can't be generically typed like that. This is probably because a that val is an instance of Function1, and instances of classes need to have actual types.

```
def notNull[T]: T => Boolean = _ != null
```

When you call notNull like above its actaully returning you a function1 instance.

```
scala> val a = notNull[String]
a: (String) => Boolean = <function1>

scala> a(null)
res5: Boolean = false

scala> a("aa")
res6: Boolean = true

scala> a(5)
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(5)
 required: String
       a(5)
         ^
```

Which I think shows why val's can't be generically typed.

Comment: Vals can be (and always are) typed, and `Function1` is a perfectly normal type for a `val`. What they can't be is _generic_ (i.e. have type arguments like `[T]`).

Comment: Err right, thats what i meant by typed - I originallyed had generically typed - but was confused over the exact terminology. Thanks.